# Xde.exe Stopped Working in WP8

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

I'm New to WP8 Development, The following Steps are done to work with WP8

1. My Main OS is Windows 8.1 enabled Virtual Technology in BIOS Setting.
2. Using VMWare 10.0 as virtual machine with windows 8 pro. 
   No Of Processors : 1 
   No Of Cores per Processors : 4 
   RAM : 4GB 
   Memory : 60GB 
   Mode : Intex VT-x / EPT or AMD-V / RVI  
   Check element : Intex VT-x / EPT or AMD-V / RVI
3. Successfully installed WP8 and VS 2012 with Update 4 & Hyper-V is enabled.
4. While running the sample application it got the error as

> "xde.exe stopped working"

Mostly  had a try with all the solution by googling..
I was struggling in this issue for past two days can any one help me out to resolve it..!!!

The Error When I try to switch on the Virtual Switch Manager..

> "An Error Occurred While retrieving list of Virtual Machine"
>  "The
>   Operation on Computer Local Host Failed"

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

Delete all the emulators in the Hyper-V Manager. From the actions menu Click on Virtual Switch Manager and remove all switches. From Control Panel->Network and Sharing Center, disable the virtual ethernet port for windows phone emulator and restart the computer. Open Visual Studio and run Windows Phone emulator.

Comment: I was not able to load the list of virtual switches.. I'm getting error and I had update it please verify it...

Comment: I have additionally deleted any Windows Phone virtual ports found in the Device Manager and followed the rest of your post and it seems to finally work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I had come up with the solution..
One of my team met had deleted all the application files that need to be executed,so the xde.exe fails to start.
I was suppose to re-install the OS and it works Fine.
Thank-you.